# Display data of a component in another component from firebase through redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React and Redux and I have been trying to make a CRUD app so that I can practice the technologies. The app has a purpose to Add a contact to a list, edit the contact or delete it, all of that while using firebase as the Backend.

So far, I can add a contact from a form component (NewContact.js) to firebase (using Thunk as the middleware) and render it to the according component (Contact.js).

[Contact.js Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpoYG.png)

Now, what I want to do is when I click on the edit icon, I should have that particular contact info on the EditContact component as a form and be able to edit it and then submit the update to firebase.

Here is the code of the NewContact.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { newContact } from "../../store/actions/ContactAction";

class NewContact extends Component {
  state = {
    fullName: null,
    phoneNumber: null,
    email: null,
    jobAndTitle: null,
    note: null,
  };

  // Methods
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.newContact(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="new-contact">
        <div className="new-contact__header">
          <h3>New Contact</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="new-contact__body">
          <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="fullName">Full Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="fullName"
              required
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <label htmlFor="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="phoneNumber"
              required
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <label htmlFor="jobAndTitle">Job & Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="jobAndTitle" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <label htmlFor="note">Note</label>
            <textarea id="note" onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
            <div className="submit-wrapper">
              <input type="submit" value="Add Contact" />
              <input type="reset" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    newContact: (contact) => dispatch(newContact(contact)),
  };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(NewContact);
```

and here is the code of the EditContact.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { firestoreConnect } from "react-redux-firebase";
import { compose } from "redux";

class EditContact extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="edit-contact">
        <div className="edit-contact__header">
          <h3>Edit Contact</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="edit-contact__body">
          <form autoComplete="off">
            <label htmlFor="fullName">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fullName" required />
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" />
            <label htmlFor="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" required />
            <label htmlFor="jobAndTitle">Job & Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="jobAndTitle" />
            <label htmlFor="note">Note</label>
            <textarea id="note"></textarea>
            <div className="submit-wrapper">
              <input type="submit" value="Edit Contact" />
              <input type="reset" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EditContact;
```

I tried to connect the **EditContact** component to firebase wit the following code, but it throws an error of **Cannot read property 'params' of undefined**

```
  const mapStateToProps = (state, myProps) => {
  console.log(state);
  const id = myProps.match.params.id;
  const contacts = state.firestore.data.contacts;
  const contact = contact ? contact[id] : null;
  return {
    contact: contact,
  };
};

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect([{ collection: "contacts" }])
)(EditContact);
```

I hope I have been clear in my post. I'd appreciate it if somebody can enlighten me.

Comment: Hello Amine! Actually you haven't been all that clear. What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: If you want to learn how to fetch/create/edit/delete data from firebase, you should check out their docs and tutorials: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore

Comment: Sorry for that, I'll edit the post and make it clearer. But basically, I want to be able to edit a data in the table (see image on the post), for that I have made a compound entitled EditContact in which I want the data to be displayed there so that I can edit it

Comment: OK. What have you tried to achieve that?

Comment: In the EditContact component I tried to retrieve the data by id thinking it would retrieve the one I clicked but I can't find my way how to do that

Comment: Could you show the code with which you tried to access firebase?

Comment: @JayCodist I edited the post and added what I have tried to do, but got an error of Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in `mapStateToProps` is the wrapped components props. `match` is not being set as a prop when `EditContact` is rendered. Since `myProps.match` is undefined a type error is thrown trying to read the property `params` on undefined. match needs to be passed as a prop to the wrapped component that renders `EditContact`.

`<EditContact params={params} />` would fix the error you are seeing assuming params had this shape

```
const params = {
  match: {
   id: <some id>
  }
};
```